# php udp works only on loopback

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I am trying to write a php udp client.

```
//Parsing values
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors","1");

$cycles = $_GET['cycles'];
$cycles = $cycles > 600 ? 600 : $cycles;
if(!isset($_GET['lport']) || $_GET['lport'] < 1500 || $_GET['lport'] > 65534) {
    $rport = 11115;
} else {
    $rport = $_GET['lport'];
}
if(!isset($_GET['sport']) || $_GET['sport'] < 1500 || $_GET['sport'] > 65534) {
    $port = 11115;
} else {
    $port = $_GET['sport'];
}
$from = isset($_GET['ip']) ? $_GET['ip'] : '127.0.0.1';

//Relevant code starts here 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', $rport);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while($cycles--) {
    $msg = "PING! " . $cycles;
    echo socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $from, $port) ? "sendto success<br>" : "sendto fail<br>";
    socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 1000, 0, $from, $port); //0x40 is MSG_DONTWAIT 
    echo "$from:$port - $buf<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
}

socket_close($socket);
```

If I call it with ?cycles=10&ip=[external ip] it won't work, it keeps printing:

> **Warning**:  socket_sendto() [function.socket-sendto]:
>   unable to write to socket [22]:
>   Invalid argument in
>   **/var/www/default/Tests/UdpTest.php**
>   on line **37**
>  sendto
>   fail
>  **Warning**: 
>   socket_recvfrom() [function.socket-recvfrom]:
>   unable to recvfrom [11]: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable in
>   **/var/www/default/Tests/UdpTest.php**
>   on line **38**
>   62.180.108.236:11116 -

If I use `?cylces=10&ip=127.0.0.1` it works as expected, receiving what it has sent. It's the same if I use two different ports and try running netcat on that machine. The external ip is a physical adress of that machine and the script is called from apache, btw.

Comment: Try changing `socket_bind` from loopback to the external IP address of the server.

Comment: Thank you very much, binding to 0.0.0.0 worked, too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the interface that you're binding to.

Binding to loop-back (`127.0.0.1`) means that you can only communicate with devices on that network interface.  And since the local machine is the only device on that interface, `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` will fail when given an address on another network.

To solve the problem, either bind to all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`) or to a specific external IP address from the server.  That will allow you to communicate with any machine on the network that IP is connected to.